# android device - Observable map() not working

Tags: ionic-framework, observable

at startpage.ts I call metroService's getResult function
I get alert well on chrome(I can get alert sayng "s" and next well), but not on android device..(only get s alert..I cant' get next alert)
how can i solve this?

Startpage.ts

```
 export class StartPage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public metro:MetroService) {
    metro.getResults("subway");
  }
```

MetroService.ts

```
getResults(keyword:string):Observable<any> {
        console.log("keyword 22233: "+keyword);
        alert("s");
        return this.http.get('/assets/metro.json')
          .map(
            result =>
            {
              alert(result.json().DATA);
              console.log(result.json().DATA.filter(item => item.STATION_NM.toLowerCase().startsWith(keyword.toLowerCase()) ))
              return result.json().DATA
                .filter(item => item.STATION_NM.toLowerCase().startsWith(keyword.toLowerCase()) )
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

replace /assets/metro.json to

```
assets/metro.json
```

Also Add Error handler and see if there is error in http.

```
  return this.http.get('/assets/metro.json')
      .map(
        result =>{
          ...
        },err =>  {alert("error is "+err.message);}
 );
```

Comment: replace /assets/metro.json  to assets/metro.json ( I am sure this will work)